# Distribution of tx fees

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

Do tx fees issued by users follow a particular distribution ? I'd guess they follow the normal distribution, but I'm not sure. More precisely, how tx.fee/tx.size is distributed in the mempool ?

Comment: I don't think that the fees would follow a normal distribution, but I haven't done the math. You can find a visual representation of the mempool at https://core.jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#24h.